# extensible architecture for angular2 app

Tags: angular, plugins

Next week our team will begin to develop an app using Angular2 as front-end. We are new to this technology but we know the basic. Our leader wants to make the app extensible by plugins. I have been looking for something similar in Google, but I didn't find anything related to this topic. I know that with Angular2, once you compile to js, all code is in 3 or 4 .js, and css similar, but I can't figure out how to incorpore a plugin to the app with out recompiling the code while the app is in production.

Comment: You could use <iframe>?

Comment: when you say 'plugin', what do you mean?  Is this a SaaS app, or is it intended that each client would install their own version? Who are the plugins for - the end user? or the client who purchases your app and sets it up? You'd have to be a lot more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: By plugin I mean something to extend functionality, just like Wordpress does. We would like to have a base application, minimal, with support for managing users and roles and a layout for the GUI, adding the rest of the application by plugin o modules. For the GUI suppose I have Angular2 components in separated files after compilation, and in production I can add more of them just copying new component files to a specific directory.

Comment: Now from a "plugin manager view" I active or desactive components (plugins). The point here is that I don't know Angular2 components beforehand, so I can't compile them all together. Instead, I need to load them dynamically, from files or DB, but without attaching the layout GUI to any specific component, using supertypes or something like this.

Comment: AFAIK angular does not support a plugin architecture by it self, i made a hack for read compiled files, however it actually makes no sense because files have to be as part of the application it selft